# Laravel 5 pagination, set number of page links

Tags: laravel-5

Requested to modify pagination so that default which reads:

```
« 1 2...18 19 20 21 22 23 24...50 51 »
```

can be edited to read as

```
« 1...19 20 21 22 23 ...51 »
```

Can the paginator be extended easily to reflect the requested styling?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something easy, you have [this package](https://github.com/Landish/Pagination). If you wanna fight a bit, you can extend the Paginator class (in L4 there was a Presenter class to extend, haven't tried that in L5 so far, don't know if it's still there).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. After digging around I decided to go ahead and stick with the "free" pagination for now.